# Javascript/InnerHTML add and get integer values

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to get the values from the textView box but it's not displaying in the p field at all, and also I am trying to add the 2 values together into one value and display it.

```js
function() {
  var x = document.forms["frm1"];
  var text = "";
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length ;i++) {
    text += x.elements[i].value + x.elements[i].value;
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<h2>Finding HTML Elements Using document.forms</h2>

<form id="frm1" action="/action_page.php">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="123"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="123"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: where is your textView box that you want to display in p element ?

Comment: fyi: int is not a valid type in js, you want to use `var` or `let`

Comment: hmm, how is this function being initialized? or how is it connected to the form? do you trigger it on submit?

Comment: Hi, I do not want it to trigger with on submit, I would want it to immediately to be displayed on the p field as soon as the page appears.

Comment: I have switched to var, but it's not working still.

Comment: I don't think you're calling the code at all, try taking it outside of the function or linking int to the submit action. lemme have an example for you really quick

Comment: here => https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-flower-wspgm?file=/index.js

Comment: There are some things that you probably want to take into consideration here, 1) you're going through all the inputs. (probably only want the text input), 2) call this function on submit, you can do that by using the. onsubmit="namefunction". 

I guess these are your first steps, My recommendation start here => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements

Comment: Hi nramirez, I would like the values to be added like for example, the value has 10 in textbox A and 20 in textbox B, the display value would be 30

Comment: You gotta use the proper type, the values in the input are text and it doesn't work as you expect if they are not Number,  try casting => text += Number(x.elements[i].value); I recommend you to take a look to this course => https://justjavascript.com/

Comment: Looks like this answer would do it => https://stackoverflow.com/a/62805977/2161256

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the function on the document load. And make these changes inside the function

```
var myValue = 0;
    
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {            
   if (x.elements[i].type === "text")
      myValue +=  Number(x.elements[i].value);
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. In your code.

> document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
> myfunction(document.forms["frm1"]);

should be called outside the function. Also, you should include a name for the function you've created.

```js
function myfunction(input) {
  var text = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    text += input[i].value;
  }
  return text;
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myfunction(document.forms["frm1"]);
```

```html
<h2>Finding HTML Elements Using document.forms</h2>

<form id="frm1" action="/action_page.php">
  <label>First name:</label> <input type="text" name="fname" value="123" /><br>
  <label>Last name:</label> <input type="text" name="lname" value="123" /><br><br>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<p id="demo"></p>
```